# Prove that there exists $b\in G$ such that $h(x)=xb^{-1} $ for all $x\in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to do every problem in my book, but I got stuck on this problem, which seems like it should be easy.

Notation:

- $A(G)$ denotes the group of all permutations of the set $G$.
- The map $\phi_a:G\to G$ is defined by $\phi_a(x)=ax$, where $a\in G$.

> Let $G$ be a group and $h\in A(G)$. Assume that $h\circ \phi_a=\phi_a \circ h$ for all $a\in G$. Prove that there exists $b\in G$ such that $h(x)=xb^{-1} $ for all $x\in G$.

Using $h\circ \phi_a=\phi_a\circ h$, I have that for all $a\in G$, $h(ax)=ah(x)$. Now I can solve for $h(x)$ and get $h(x)=a^{-1}h(ax)$. From here it seems that no matter how I manipulate it, I can't get it into the required form. I've also tried deducing more information about $h$ by seeing how it behaves on the identity elemnent, so $h(e)=h(aa^{-1}) = ah(a^{-1})$ but so far I have nothing.

I would greatly appreciate any hints as to how I should proceed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have proven that $h(ax)=a\,h(x)$ ***for all*** $a\in G$.  With $x:=e$, we get $h(a)=a\,h(e)$ for every $a\in G$.  If $b$ is the inverse of $h(e)$, then [...].  I leave the rest to you.

Comment: Of course! It's clear to me now. Thanks!